# Should the tag [offline-reinforcement-learning] be added?

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-synonyms

**Question**: Should there be a tag for [offline-reinforcement-learning](https://ai.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/offline-reinforcement-learning) on AI Stack Exchange?

**Background**: It seems that the current relevant tags for *offline RL* are [tag:off-policy methods], [offline-learning](https://ai.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/offline-learning), and [batch-learning](https://ai.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/batch-learning) (the second of those tags being a synonym of the third). When I looked at the [batch-learning](https://ai.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/batch-learning) tag, the [questions](https://ai.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/batch-learning) seemed to be split between *offline RL* and questions regarding *batches* of data (e.g. for neural network training) - two very distinct types of questions. I feel that a tag that distinguishes *offline RL* from *batch learning* may be helpful for the AI Stack Exchange community.

From my own experience, it looks like *offline RL* is emerging as a more specific term in the research community throughout the past few years. For example, a survey by Sergei Levine et al. in 2020 had a fairly substantial paragraph (second paragraph of section 2.2 [here](https://arxiv.org/pdf/2005.01643.pdf)) that discusses the distinctions between the terms *off-policy learning*, *batch learning*, and *offline RL*. In summary, *offline RL* is a subset of *off-policy* learning that doesn't involve any more interaction with the environment, a major difference. Also, they explicitly state that using the term *batch learning* in place of *offline RL* can be confusing.

While it isn't discussed in the survey, I find that the *offline learning* seems to be too general of a tag for *offline RL* questions, for example, due to the vastly different algorithms and intuitions used to find an optimal policy versus training a classifier. In addition, the Wikipedia [page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Offline_learning) on *offline learning* explicitly states that "*Offline learning* is working in *batch mode*", again causing possible confusion if *offline learning* is used as a tag instead of *offline RL*. Finally, I think using a generic *reinforcement learning* tag is also too general due to the different algorithms and concerns in the field of *offline RL*.

I haven't made a tag yet, and I'm mainly wondering if my thought process is correct since I have never created a tag. Also, I'm unsure if there are any unwritten rules regarding tags that I am unaware of. For those wondering, I asked this question because I was surprised to find that there was no [offline-reinforcement-learning](https://ai.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/offline-reinforcement-learning) tag when answering a question on *offline RL*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure, creating a new tag like that sounds good to me. Short answer, but don't really have anything else to say... if you'd like to, please go ahead :)

Comment: Thanks @Dennis Soemers. Should I go through the 16 questions with the [batch-learning] tag and retag the ~8 or so to [offline-reinforcement-learning], or should I leave old questions as they are?

Comment: @DeepQZero It's good to edit tags of old questions (when appropriate) too!

Comment: I made the changes. Thanks! I wanted to make the tag synonym [offline-rl], but I guess I don't have enough reputation.

Comment: I've gone ahead and added the synonym, @DeepQZero. One other thing that would be appreciated is if you could write a short [tag wiki excerpt](https://ai.stackexchange.com/edit-tag-wiki/2704), giving some guidance on when that tag should be used.

Comment: @Mithical Good idea! I will try to add the except within a week. I'm not an expert in the area, but I definitely can provide a start. Also, thanks for showing me the tag font in markdown - I didn't know about it.